# tflearn label encoding with large number of classes

Tags: python, tflearn

I am trying to adapt the [Convolutional Neural Net example of tflearn](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/blob/master/examples/nlp/cnn_sentence_classification.py) to do a classification with ~12000 distinct class labels and more than 1 million training examples. The number of labels is apparently a problem in terms of memory consumption when one-hot encoding them. I first map my string labels to continuous integers, I then pass these as a list to the `to_categorical()` function. The following code leads to a MemoryError:

```
trainY = to_categorical(trainY, nb_classes=n_classes)
```

Do I have to encode the labels like this or should I use a different loss function than cross-entropy? Can I train in batches with tflearn - can I pass a generator to the `DNN.fit()` function?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Are you trying to process all your labels at once? The approach can be adapted without too much change, but you're going to need to process these images in batches. It's just way too much to load into memory at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the regression layer [link](http://tflearn.org/layers/estimator/), you can specify that the labels that are feed in should be one-hot encoded on the run

```
tflearn.layers.regression(incoming_net,
                          loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',
                          batch_size = 64,
                          to_one_hot = True,
                          n_classes = 12000)
```

In this way you should not have a memory error, because labels will be encoded in batches while training.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed! :-)